# Is MIL-STD-1553 still used in modern aircraft?

Tags: avionics

I am working on an assignment for my "Avionics Systems Design" class and I want to use MIL-STD-1553 for my aircraft system. But according to some shady blogs this STD has been deprecated or superseded by MIL-STD-1773.
If I don't want to use an optical solution, what is the best bus for my system?

Comment: According to Wiki, 1773 is 1553 with fiber physical layer, so strictly speaking it doesn't "supersede" 1553. It's more like a variant that has its own application, e.g. EMP resistance, longer transmission distance and higher data rate. Also, I really don't think fiber so prevalent on airplanes now that the copper version doesn't exist at all so the answer to your question is probably yes? Also in your assignment you probably care about logic than physical so why care?

Comment: MIL-STD-1553 buses have too low data rate, leading to multiple parallel buses to support peak data rates, hence the 1773; at least as far as I understand the history of these two. Also check SAE AIR4508A if you have access, it provides some background on the two specs you mention.

Comment: Are you wanting to design a system for military applications or civil applications? What size aircraft?

Comment: Your instructor has given you the materials you need to do the assignment, and thus won't mind if you ignore advice from blogs that you've already figured out are untrustworthy.

Comment: I can say 1553 is still used.  I'm not allowed to say more. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MIL STD 1553 is alive and still in use.  Backwards compatibility will keep it around for some time.  Not only is it used in aircraft but also on spacecraft.

It tends to be used for control applications and lower data rates.  High volume data, for example from sensors, will employ different bus structures.  Many control, communications and guidance applications can readily be accomplished with 1553.

Having said that, I cannot say whether it is right for you application, as I know little about your application.  Noise, data rates, latency and other factors may cause you to look at different interconnection architectures. There are many competing bus/LAN structures.